# How to check when latest element of Adapter is shown on screen?

Tags: android

I have my own `Adapter` extended from a `BaseAdapter`. I need to know when the latest element from the `Adapter` is shown on user's screen when user scrolls to it. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the onDraw() method in the element's view. When onDraw() is called, you know that the element is on the screen. Design wise, you could have an observer in each element's view. The adapter will register itself (or a different client) as an observer to the last/latest element's view. When the view is drawn, it will notify the observer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It will Refresh your adapter, notifies if any change..

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        // ...

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {             
            boolean isLastRowShown = view.getLastVisiblePosition() == (view.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
```